# How to have default (pre) zoom of category axis in amcharts 4?

Tags: graph, charts, zooming, amcharts, amcharts4

For a chart like this
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/NmNLoL

```
function categoryAxisZoomed(ev) {
var axis = ev.target;
var start = axis.getPositionLabel(axis.start);
var end = axis.getPositionLabel(axis.end);
console.log("New range: " + start + " -- " + end);
}
```

How can I add a pre zoom to max level so that when a page loads, I see only one category.
I want to do this only for mobile.
Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use zoom to values like this

```
function zoomAxis(pass parameters) {
  valueAxis.zoomToValues("start", "end");
}
```

For references: http://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/zooming-axis-via-api-or-external-scrollbar/